# Does using thread alter the result of your code?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, image-processing, neural-network, python-multiprocessing

**So I wrote a function that returns a dictionary when it is called. This what it looks like**

```
def path(image_file):
    Some function that returns a dictionary
    return co_ordinates


def Draw():
    image_file = "Data/test2.png"
    print(path(image_file))

Draw()
```

result for this

```
{(60, 63, 65): (35, 49), (40, 40, 40): (35, 44), (85, 85, 85): (35, 45), (61, 61, 61): (16, 4), (59, 59, 59): (16, 5), (56, 56, 56): (16, 6), (52, 52, 52): (16, 7), (48, 48, 48): (16, 8), (44, 44, 44): (16, 9), (39, 39, 39): (16, 10), (35, 35, 35): (16, 11), (30, 30, 30): (16, 12), (23, 23, 23): (16, 13), (17, 17, 17): (16, 14), (12, 12, 12): (16, 15), (7, 7, 7): (16, 16), (3, 3, 3): (16, 17), (141, 141, 141): (6, 7), (97, 97, 97): (6, 8), (112, 112, 112): (6, 10), (80, 80, 80): (11, 8), (60, 63, 106): (18, 36), (187, 187, 187): (22, 37), (116, 116, 116): (7, 7), (62, 62, 62): (7, 10), (145, 187, 187): (7, 33), (145, 187, 166): (16, 37), (171, 171, 171): (8, 6), (124, 84, 65): (20, 33), (128, 128, 128): (9, 7), (174, 174, 174): (34, 44), (98, 98, 98): (9, 9), (41, 41, 41): (9, 10), (81, 81, 81): (10, 6), (63, 63, 63): (10, 11), (79, 79, 79): (11, 9), (165, 125, 86): (23, 33), (145, 104, 65): (11, 33), (101, 101, 101): (12, 7), (92, 92, 92): (12, 10), (60, 84, 126): (19, 32), (130, 130, 130): (13, 7), (124, 124, 124): (13, 10), (165, 187, 166): (13, 29), (140, 140, 140): (14, 6), (137, 137, 137): (14, 7), (152, 152, 152): (14, 10), (121, 121, 121): (14, 11), (109, 74, 58): (17, 37), (142, 144, 145): (17, 38), (51, 55, 57): (17, 39), (57, 62, 65): (17, 40), (69, 74, 78): (19, 40), (91, 99, 102): (19, 42), (79, 85, 88): (17, 43), (60, 63, 64): (17, 44), (86, 87, 87): (17, 45), (138, 165, 146): (19, 33), (181, 167, 139): (19, 34), (44, 52, 53): (19, 36), (24, 26, 27): (19, 37), (64, 69, 73): (19, 39), (74, 80, 85): (19, 41), (90, 98, 101): (19, 43), (77, 83, 85): (19, 44), (87, 90, 92): (19, 45), (62, 66, 68): (19, 46), (165, 187, 187): (20, 37), (102, 63, 65): (23, 32), (187, 187, 147): (22, 32), (60, 104, 147): (22, 33), (187, 146, 106): (23, 37), (169, 198, 226): (25, 7), (183, 183, 183): (25, 8), (183, 212, 241): (26, 9), (183, 169, 198): (35, 13), (169, 183, 212): (35, 14)}
```

**But then I run it using a thread because I have another function I need it to run with**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=Sketch_Pad).start()
    Thread(target=Draw).start()
```

this time I get this result:

```
{(0, 0, 0): (3, 37), (60, 63, 65): (35, 38), (145, 187, 166): (19, 33), (40, 40, 40): (34, 44), (85, 85, 85): (34, 45), (124, 84, 65): (20, 33), (60, 63, 106): (18, 36), (60, 84, 126): (19, 37), (165, 187, 187): (20, 37), (165, 187, 147): (19, 35), (145, 187, 187): (19, 36), (187, 187, 187): (22, 37), (102, 63, 65): (23, 32), (165, 125, 86): (23, 33), (187, 187, 147): (22, 32), (60, 104, 147): (22, 33), (187, 146, 106): (23, 37), (76, 40, 112): (24, 8), (40, 76, 148): (24, 9), (112, 40, 40): (24, 15), (148, 219, 255): (24, 14), (183, 255, 255): (28, 7), (76, 148, 219): (28, 14), (148, 76, 40): (27, 14), (40, 40, 112): (27, 7), (112, 183, 255): (28, 12), (76, 40, 40): (27, 12), (40, 112, 183): (34, 10), (148, 183, 255): (28, 8), (112, 40, 76): (30, 7), (183, 183, 169): (31, 12), (183, 183, 183): (31, 13), (183, 212, 241): (33, 14), (169, 198, 226): (32, 13), (169, 183, 212): (34, 15), (57, 60, 62): (35, 46), (63, 66, 68): (34, 48), (67, 71, 73): (34, 49), (151, 157, 162): (35, 0), (124, 132, 137): (35, 1), (97, 106, 112): (35, 2), (93, 102, 109): (35, 5), (92, 101, 108): (35, 6), (110, 118, 124): (35, 7), (60, 62, 64): (35, 39), (59, 62, 64): (35, 42), (58, 61, 63): (35, 43), (39, 39, 39): (35, 44), (81, 81, 81): (35, 45), (57, 59, 61): (35, 47), (56, 59, 61): (35, 48), (55, 58, 60): (35, 49)}
```

So I decided to pass it through variables dict and dictw respectively the result was

```
print(dict.__len__())
52
```

and

```
print(dictw.__len__())
77
```

Can someone explain what could be happening I don't really understand what is happening an this is running on python 3

Comment: If the function creating the path is self contained and only it meddles with the final data, terhe should be no differences - but you don't show that code, and moreover, you've tagged this as "neural-network" when not even a hint of the libraries you are using for that show.

Do you have deterministic results across runs of this code in single-thread mode? Does the result generate make sense in both cases?

Comment: it's quite long. but what it does is that it return the rgb value and coordinate of every pixel in an image after getting a threshold for all of them

Comment: for the libraries i'm using for now i'm using import time
from statistics import mean,
from threading import Thread,
import numpy as np,
import pyautogui,
import pygame,
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab,
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

Comment: Could it be a problem with accessing Memory